# How to use Firefox add-on SDK / places/bookmarks API from Python

Tags: python, sqlite, firefox, sdk

I am looking for a kick-start on how to access Firefox bookmarks, folders and tabs from Python using Firefox SDK. 
I already tested accessing places.sqlite through the SQLite3 library, but it can run in read-only mode since Firefox locks the database while in use.

How do I initialize the SDK from Python (3.x but I would be willing to use 2.7 too, in case) and send basic commands like create a folder, create a bookmark or tag it?

As you might have already guessed I am learning and rather inexperienced...
Yet I searched quite a bit without finding anything of value other than this link [Manipulating bookmarks using Places](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Manipulating_bookmarks_using_Places) that clearly uses some other language.

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated a little further, or better: asked to an experienced friend.

The answer seems to be: you cannot invoke Firefox's SDK from anything different than Javascript. It has no bindings for other languages, also because they could not work in Firefox.

In addition to that the guide I linked might be old, since Firefox has moved onto supporting web extensions.

It looks like I might have to shift my focus back to JS if I want to pursue this project.